# Наложение маски из индексов на список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Необходимо по маске индексов получить список групп элементов списка. Пример:

Маска:

```py
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Массив:

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
```

Результат (после наложении маски):

```py
[['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], ['k']]
```

Можно ли это сделать с помощью встроенных функций для работы со списками?

Comment: Из встроенных подходит [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), но надо селекторы к нужному виду привести.

Comment: Или [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (см. [ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272249/10941639)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через генераторы именно для списков маск вида `list(list(int()))`:

```
masks = [[3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
data  = "abcdefghijklmnop"
retr  = [[data[i] for i in mask] for mask in masks]
print(retr)
```

Стандартных функций для таких действий не знаю, но ее можно сделать самому по принципу выше.

Comment: `list` можно убрать

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы нашел приемлемое решение.

```
mask = [[3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
result = [list(map(lambda x: values[x], each)) for each in mask]
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
[['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], ['k']]
```

Правда встает вопрос, насколько это оптимальнее варианта с вложенным генератором, как в ответе Shamus Rezol.

Comment: Ну вы через `list(map(lambda x:` просто сделали аналог `list comprehension`, только больше сил и средств на это затратили